# Buddhism view on idol worship?

Tags: personal-practice, worship, general-buddhism

I would like to make a little temple in my home. Something that has my little singing bowl and its' pillow and a container for incense and maybe a little Buddha in a pagoda. Like a desktop thing. I'd use it for meditation.

Is this frowned upon or allowed or even addressed? I see little temples at businesses and I didnt know how that all worked. Honestly I dont really care about a reputation or anything like that. I just need a tenable, defendable position about it if asked and you people are smarter than I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Pali suttas, the Buddha seemed to praise honoring him & his virtues, i.e., for the right purpose (such as did not occur in the case of [Vakkali](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.087x.wlsh.html), who was rebuked).

If a Buddha pagoda helps you practise better, be more mindful, virtuous & wise, it is generally held to be praiseworthy.

Comment: Thank you so much. That example of Vakkali was right on point and answered my question completely.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu Really nice question and answer.